# ExtJS does not recognize a new folder

Tags: javascript, extjs

I working on a ExtJS project. This is how my folder structure looks like. I have no problem with all folders but 'util' folder is not recognized by extjs.

[image]

This is what I have in AjaxManager.js

```
Ext.define('FBT.util.AjaxManager', {
  alternateClassName: 'AjaxManager',
  singleton: true,

  test: function() {
    alert('test it!');
  }
});
```

When I try to do

```
FBT.util.AjaxManager.test();
```

it does not work and this is what I got in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AjaxManager' of undefined

As I said, I have no problems with classes that are placed in the view or controller folder. Any idea what's going on?

Thanks,

Angelo

Comment: Have you required `FBT.util.AjaxManager`?

Comment: You are right, it was missing, but is there any way to have all FBT.util.* classes automatically loaded?

Comment: Try `requires: ['FBT.util.*']`.

Comment: I mean in every class so I don't have to add requires to each class that needs some class